# Passing passwords, hashes and salts through WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, hash

The passwords of users are hashed in the database with a salt. The salt is stored in the database too.

I have a WCF service with a method that accepts a username and password from the client. The WCF service has access to the database, the client obviously doesn't.

I could pass the password in plain text, however, sending a password to a WCF service in plain text sounds like a horrible idea.

The solution would be to pass the hash instead. However, I cannot calculate the hash as I do not have the salt, which is stored in the database. I could create a service method to retrieve the salt, however, I'm not sure if this is the best way to resolve this issue.

What's the best solution for this problem? Is retrieving the salt first a good idea?

Comment: Passing Username/Password over the net without security seems like a horrible idea. At the same time, username/password authentication is already properly implemented in https. Why don't you use those features instead of home-brewing it anew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main security issue is that someone can intercept credentials (username and password) so they get access to the WCF service.

Sending the password or the hash are quite the same (it's just another way to call password). If someone retrieve it, they can authenticate to the WCF service. You should look at HTTP Basic and HTTP Digest authentication for more information.

Instead you should use a secure protocol such as SSL to secure the connection and prevent MITM.